# mercurial hg update abort: no such file or directory

Tags: file, mercurial, directory, abort

I'm working on a C++ project on OpenSuse Linux box using mercurial versioning and recently did a pull from our server repository to my local working directory.  I just tried to do an hg update, but got the following error message:

```
abort: No such file or directory: /home/username/Documents/dev/proj/.hg/store/data/images/general/picture.png.d
```

I'm pretty new to Mercurial and was wondering if there's any way I can troubleshoot this.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository may be corrupt. Start with running `hg verify` to see if there are any errors. The Mercurial wiki has [a page dedicated to this](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) that should help you out as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I followed the link, and ran hg verify on my local repository.  After some fiddling around, I found that a fresh clone of the repository had no problems when running verify, but that right after running "make clean" hg verify would generate issues.  It turns out that an rm command in the Makefile for cleaning out files with extension ".d" was being executed that affected the hg files.  This was updated and resolved the issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: and if running `hg verify` and not getting any errors and still getting `no such file or directory` ? what to do then?